# python subprocess.Popen is terminating python

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I have some code in a python script that runs an executable like this

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(["C:\executable.exe", "arg1", "arg2"], shell=False)
```

I've also tried

```
subprocess.call("C:\executable.exe", "arg1, "arg2"])
```

With the same results.

The program runs but this program also closes the program that called it, this is true whether I run it from the command line or python. The problem is I need to wait for the execution of the program to finish and then continue with the rest of the script. Is there a way to prevent the application from closing my python console?

Comment: "this program also closes the program that called it" - what program are you dealing with? This information may be important for answering your question.

Comment: It's one of my company's internal programs our devs built. It's a 32bit application with a gui. Beyond that I don't know much about it. what I do know is that according to documentation windows consoles will automatically close when the process attached to it terminates, which I think is what is happening here.